# Sitemap for WordPress extension

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, magento

I'm using an extension to integrate a WordPress blog into my eCommerce site. WordPress is installed in its own directory with a link called blog on my home page. I used a free extension to do this.

My question is, do I need to create a separate sitemap for Google for the blog? 
If so how do I submit it? If not will Google pick up all of the blog articles via my current Magento sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a separate sitemap for the blog. One sitemap can cover any pages in your site including those in different pieces of software. This is because, generally speaking, the search engines don't know or care about the software being used to generate your content. They just see the final output of all of it.

Now you may want to create separate sitemaps simply because it is easier to do and/or organize. But this would be for your own sanity's sake and not for any SEO purposes.